# SPQuery needs initialization?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query

i stumbled upon a curious line here it looks like:

```
foreach(var item in someList.GetItems(new SPQuery {Query = "<Where />"}){...};
```

and i wonder if i could just omit the initialization of the Query property since it only contains an empty Where clause anyway... however, maybe the Query should be initialized with something because it might be null and cause unintended behavior or something. Can somebody confirm this?

Or could i simply use: `someList.GetItems(new SPQuery()).foo()` ?

also, since the SPQuery object isn't used afterwards and i only need to get all the elements in the list once `someList.Items` should do the trick, right?

and just in case you're wondering: this line is by a  colleague of mine but i can't ask him because he's on vacation -.-

however a co-worker hinted at the possibility that `someList.GetItems(spQuery)` is faster than `someList.Items` which would at least explain why the `GetItems(...)` is in that line in the first place but i'm still somewhat puzzled about the Query initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was state of the art some time long ago...

The Items property is not cached and therefore always requests all items from the database again, but you can avoid this with the same result as your code:

```
SPListItemCollection items = SPContext.Current.List.Items;
foreach(SPListItem item in items){
             ...
}
```

some explanation: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018012626/http://apmblog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/01/11/the-wrong-way-to-iterate-through-sharepoint-splist-items/)